# How to get last 3 data of last 3 week days from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, max

I have a table consisting of stock market's daily data. It consists of various number of rows for each day.I have a column named 'High' in the table. Now I need to calculate MAX(High) for last 3 week days. For ex:- if today is Wednesday I need to calculate MAX of last week's friday and this week's monday,tuesday. I know that I can do this if I know the date manually using a query like this.

```
Select MAX(HIGH) from table_name where date>='date'
```

But I don't want to do like this i just want to automate this with a program written in PHP. How can i Achieve this any help in both either PHP or SQL is appreciable. My table just has 6 columns

```
date,time,open,high,low,close
```

say suppose if my table is like this

```
date        time       open      high     low     close
2015-05-06  09:30:00   2012.50   2020.5   2016.5  2014.0
2015-05-06  09:31:00   2013.50   2021.5   2014.5  2016.0
2015-05-06  09:32:00   2014.50   2021.75  2017.5  2013.0
2015-05-07  09:30:00   2011.50   2019.5   2018.5  2014.0
2015-05-07  09:31:00   2014.50   2022.5   2016.5  2015.0
2015-05-07  09:32:00   2012.50   2026.5   2017.5  2016.0
2015-05-08  09:30:00   2010.50   2024.5   2015.5  2017.0
2015-05-08  09:31:00   2013.50   2026.5   2017.5  2018.0
2015-05-08  09:32:00   2014.50   2028.5   2015.5  2019.0
2015-05-08  09:33:00   2014.50   2022.5   2017.5  2012.0
2015-05-11  09:30:00   2017.50   2025.5   2018.5  2013.0
2015-05-11  09:31:00   2018.50   2027.5   2019.5  2016.0
2015-05-11  09:32:00   2019.50   2024.5   2011.5  2017.0
2015-05-11  09:33:00   2020.50   2026.5   2017.5  2014.0
2015-05-12  09:30:00   2018.50   2023.5   2018.5  2018.0
2015-05-12  09:31:00   2017.50   2024.5   2017.5  2014.0
2015-05-12  09:32:00   2018.50   2023.5   2018.5  2013.0
2015-05-12  09:33:00   2017.50   2024.5   2019.5  2014.0
2015-05-12  09:34:00   2016.50   2023.5   2016.5  2012.0
2015-05-12  09:35:00   2017.50   2025.5   2018.5  2011.0
```

and if today's date is 2015-05-13(wednesday) I need MAX(high) of last 3 week days i.e 2015-05-12,11,08 which is 2028.5.

Comment: This is a really good question. I think it can be improved a bit with some sample data and your expected results, so others can see exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Open and Close are keywords, you should change the column names

Comment: ^So are date and time, just throwing that in there.

Comment: create an sql fiddle and i will show you how to do this with php

Comment: Also, I'm a little confused. If the day is Wednesday, wouldn't you want Friday, Monday, and Tuesday?

Comment: Thanq McAdam i will make the changes.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you only have data on "week days".

```
select max(high)
from table_name t join
     (select date
      from table_name
      group by date
      order by date desc
      limit 3
     ) dates
     on t.date = dates.date;
```

Presumably, you either want a condition on the stock or a `group by`, but this is based on your sample query.

You can make this more efficient by adding a `where` clause.  Typically, the last three working days would be within the last week, or so:

```
select max(high)
from table_name t join
     (select date
      from table_name
      where date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day)
      group by date
      order by date desc
      limit 3
     ) dates
     on t.date = dates.date;
```

Comment: I understand his question as asking how to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use date_sub function for this case:

```
select max(high) from table_name where date > date_sub(date, INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct query:

```
select top 3 date, max(high) from table_name order by date desc
```